# Common Lisp: predicate returns an error when given a function as a parameter

Tags: common-lisp

Just started playing around with Common Lisp (with [L(λ)THW](http://learnlispthehardway.org/try-lisp/)), and typed in `(atom atom)` expecting to get `nil` as a result. But instead I got the error

*ERROR[!]: Variable `ATOM' is unbound.*

The same result is when I try to "feed" any function to any predicate, as far as I can tell. Why is this so? And specifically, aren't functions (or expressions) just lists?

Comment: Not really. Common LISP is a LISP-2, it has separate namespaces for functions and variables. You have to apply `function` or `#'` to refer to the function `atom` instead of the variable `atom` in an argument list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Common Lisp is a Lisp-2. This means variables and functions reside in different namespaces. To use a function as a value, you must fetch it from the function namespace with the function `function`:

```
(atom (function atom))
```

As a shortcut for this, you can prepend it with `#'` instead:

```
(atom #'atom)
```

Comment: It may also be helpful to compare with the error you get if you do something like `(let ((f (lambda (x) x))) (f f))`.  Note that it's not the same kind of error.